# MySQL group_by and max not working as expected

Tags: mysql, json, group-by

I have a fairly simple MySQL situation. There's a table with JSON values in it that I want to find the max of.

Something like this:

```
ID | data
1  | { value: 1 }
1  | { value: 2 }
1  | { value: 3 }
2  | { value: 4 }
...
```

When I query via something simple like this:

```
SELECT id, max(data->'$.value')
  FROM table
 GROUP BY id
```

I'm getting simply wrong values. Something like:

```
ID | max...
1  | 2
2  | 4
```

When I debug my query by dropping in a group_concat to see what's being aggregating over:

```
SELECT id, group_concat(data->'$.value'), max(data->'$.value')
  FROM table
 GROUP BY id
```

Suddenly the max function returns the right value and the group_concat shows the list of values it theoretically should be maximizing over.

What's going on? A quick search reveals very little. Thanks!

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iGwzhnWyDEo9ciApaJq6uF/0

Comment: If it's really happening, it sounds like a bug in the MySQL optimizer.

Comment: Yea, I didn't search for the smallest reproducible sample since the full system is a little more complicated than the above example and was hoping it was a recognizable problem without it.

Seems like it's more complicated and probably to do with how the JSON table is generated, so I'll look deeper into it.

For reference, the ID is actually a generated column, generated by extracting data out of the JSON data (though referencing the JSON field directly doesn't change the results).

Comment: JSON is still a relatively new feature, I wouldn't find any bugs in using it surprising.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve].

Comment: Was able to parse my input better for a better example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iGwzhnWyDEo9ciApaJq6uF/3

Reused your db-fiddle. Thanks for setting that up.

Comment: Note that adding a group_concat to the query produces the right results, but the plain query produces incorrect results.

Comment: Do you like the results better when using `max(cast(data->'$.data.curr_value' AS unsigned))`? If yes you expect numeric sorting where lexicographic sorting is used. Doesn't explain why the behavior changes when using `group_concat()` along with it though.

Comment: Ah, I can't believe I forgot lexicographic sorting as a problem. Presumed MySQL casts appropriately based on the JSON datatype based on other examples I've seen.

Comment: casting it as SIGNED works fine, though I agree, the group_concat implicitly converting the sort is really weird.

Comment: You should consider the result of `data->'$.value'` is a JSON document, not a VARCHAR, not a number. Maybe the comparison operator is not working well on your version of MySQL. By the way what specific version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I was wondering if it might be something like that, although I also assumed that the result would be a number, not a string.

Comment: It's the latest MySQL RDS instance one can spin up in Amazon, which I believe is 8.0.15.

And yes, that makes sense, I presumed, incorrectly, that MySQL converts the JSON document type appropriately, since it seems to typically work in most cases (comparisons, for example, properly convert between the JSON document type and string/bool/number per the JSON spec).